# Proving a representation is not semisimple

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

When trying to show that a representation $\rho:G\to GL(V)$  is not completely reducible (semisimple), is it enough to find a subspace $W\subset V$ which is $\rho(G)$-invariant and show that the complementary subspace is not $\rho(G)$-invariant?

Comment: There is no "the" complementary subspace. You need to show that there is no complementary subspace which is invariant.